# Selecting a value from a enum drop down using razor code ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

I have a EnumDropDownListFor that looks like this.

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Countries, null, new { @class = "selectpicker" })
```

'selectpicker' is from [this](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) library plugin.

And countries is an enum that looks like this.

```
public enum Countries
{
    [Display(Name = "United States")]
    UnitedStates,
    [Display(Name = "Afghanistan")]
    Afghanistan,
}
```

Is there a way to make one of the enum values selected, by giving it a 'selected' attribute value via razor code?

ex. The enum is countries (United States, Mexico, Brazil, etc.) I can pass into my viewmodel either a name like 'United States', 'UnitedStates' or a index value like 3 and I want that country to get a 'selected' attribute.

Comment: Just set the value of property `Countries` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view. e.g. `model.Countries = .Countries.Afghanistan; return View(model);` and "Afghanistan" will be selected

Comment: What if I have multiple selected? The enumdropdownlistfor uses a selectpicker plugin element that might have multiple values selected.

Comment: You cannot use a `<select multiple>` to bind to an `enum` :)  (and in any case, if you wanted to select many, you would need the `[Flags]` attribute on your enum but that will not work with `EnumDropDownListFor()`)